# How to sort the value based on an attached picture in python

Tags: python, sorting

I got an image and this image has a lot of bounding box with their coordinate, which is top left coordinates. I want to sort the values like the below order from images.

order : (3,5), (5,7), (9,3), (2,14), (4,15), (7,14)

Could you please solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Can you try solving it first, then come back when you have a [mre]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you say that sorting is based on addition of `x` and `y` coordinate?

```
lst = [(3,5), (5,7), (2,14), (9,3),(4,15), (7,14)]
lst.sort(key=sum)
print(lst)
```

Comment: @HeapOverflow, it takes the sum of every tuple and sorts based on that.

Comment: Yeah I know. But why wrap it?

Comment: I mean, `sum` is a perfectly fine function already. Why wrap it with another function like that? Why not simply `lst.sort(key=sum)`?

Comment: Yeah. thats perfetly doable. Thanks. Edited